# Python - Django - modify fields in serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, generics, serialization

i have the following setup:

I have a basic blog and article relation, where i get all blogs and its associated articles:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    articles = ArticleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'articles')
        depth = 0


class BlogViewSet(ViewSetMixin, GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

Now i want to keep things as the are, BUT:

When the list view is called (e.g. api/blogs), only the ids of the articles should be shipped, so i extended my viewset to:

```
class BlogViewSet(ViewSetMixin, GenericAPIView, ..):

    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # pseudo code
        if self.context['request'].action == 'list':
            serializer = super(BlogViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, *kwargs)
            serializer.fields['articles'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
            serializer.is_valid()
            return serializer
```

i just wanted to override the corresponding *articles* field with a PrimaryKeyRelatedField, so only id´s get shipped.

But i get empty results(no blogs and articles at all) and i have no idea why... any ideas or suggestions?

thanks and greetings!

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right thing to do - it would be better to define separate serializer classes and just return the relevant one. But also note that the right method to override is `get_serializer_class`.

Comment: is there no way to do this without having multiple serializer classes? should i maybe consider moving the required business logic to to_representation method from serailizer? i thought of this to be standard api design... ?